# Web Deploy an Application to a remote IIS website

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have 1 IIS server named 'WEB'.
Most of my production applications run as an application in 'Default Web Site' at C:\inetpub\wwwroot.
For development I have a seperate website (yes on the same IIS..) named 'Development' at C:\inetpub\wwwdevelopment.

I'm used to publishing my website in Visual Studio using the filesystem method. So I simply created a subfolder 'myApp' in wwwdevelopment and published to \WEB\wwwdevelopment\myApp and on the server I converted 'myApp' to an application.

I've played around a bit with Web Deploy and finally got it to work using the Web Deploy 3.5 msi installer.

1. Configured Web Deployment on my 'Development' website
2. Imported the publishing file in Visual Studio:

[image: Web deployment screenshot]

With this as a result:

[image]

For some reason it has dumped my files in the root of the 'Development' site and duplicated the whole thing to the MyApp folder (I've converted into an Application myself to try it out).

Answer (score 1):

Okay..  feeling pretty dumb right now..

Setting site name to **Development\MyApp** fixed my problem..

Weird that I haven't seen this in any guides!

Comment: This worked brilliantly! Couldn't find this anywhere.